# Getting rid of heat from peltier tile

Tags: experimental-physics

I'm using a peltier tile to cool down something. However, the other side of the tile gets really hot and I want to find an easy way get rid of the heat that doesn't get used up (not a coolant) or require a lot of energy (not a fan). I was thinking of using another peltier tile and getting back some electric current but that doesn't seem to work. Would it be possible to coat the hot side with some material that would turn the heat into light (like the material used in LEDs or tungsten?)? Any suggestions / ideas?

Note the setup has to be quite thin.

Answer (score 1):

get the biggest copper heatsink you can find and stick it onto the hot side of the junction sandwich with heat sink grease. orient the junction wafer so the hot side faces up. heatsinks like this are used to passively cool microprocessor chips and can be found in electronics junk shops or on-line. a small fan will GREATLY increase the effectiveness of the heatsink and require very little power.

Comment: Yup. No such thing as a free lunch.